# Should my vote depend on current score of a question of answer?

Tags: discussion

In principle it's simple, upvoting when something is good, downvoting when something is bad. But let's suppose I come across a good, but not a great Q/A. This Q/A already has a score of 50+ or so; should I still upvote it?

More general, should I vote independently of the current score or should I think something like:
This Q/A deserves a score of 50, hence upvote when it's below 50, do nothing when it's about 50 and maybe even downvote, when it's above 100?

Comment: A relevant consideration is that you only have a limited number of votes per-day. I interpret this as the system telling me that I should only vote when I feel strongly, and therefore I *won't* upvote a decent question that already has a large number of votes.

Comment: Only the content of a post should matter for your urge to vote. Score, age,  reputation of the OP, time of day, if you already had a coffee or not should not influence any decision

Comment: *"In principal it's simple, upvoting when something is good, downvoting when something is bad"* - and don't vote when the content doesn't deserve either way. There are three options, sometimes people seem to forget that and then they start to vote without confidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> should I still upvote it?

Can't tell you how to vote.

But the principle you quoted earlier still stands:

> upvoting when something is good, downvoting when something is bad

But your real question here is:

> should I vote independently of the current score

My point of view on this is yes, you should disregard the current score. View the post as if it had no votes on it. I appreciate that there may be bias attached to the score (subconscious or otherwise), which is just something to fight against.